# Excel interop changes not reflecting

Tags: c#, excel, interop, uipath

I am working on a uipath project and have created a activity using c# and interop the aim of the activity is to format the date column in excel to a particular format.
Unfortunately when I am reading the file through uipath it does not have those changes even though I can see the changes when I open excel.
Also on clicking on the cell for editing and then saving the excel without any changes I am getting those changes.
Need some help.
Thanks

Comment: Please post some code so others can try to replicate what you're seeing.

Comment: Posting the exact code might be difficult as I have network restrictions. I am creating a excel application object then work book and work sheet. In worksheet I am trying to do is range.entirecolumn.numberfirmat="dd/MM/yyyy".

Comment: You don't have to post the exact code - just a snippet that demonstrates the problem...the last time I did this in prep for posting a question here - my snippet worked, which led me to figure out the problem myself.